# Pandas DataFrame to_dict fails after drop_duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, let's just call it `df`.

`return df.to_dict(orient="records")` dutifully spits out a list of dicts.

But if I do

```
df.drop_duplicates
return df.to_dict(orient="records")
```

it fails and says:

> 'function' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you miss `()`, because without the `()` the [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) just refers to the function, so `df` becomes a copy of the function, not the result of executing it (thanks [andychase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235922/pandas-dataframe-to-dict-fails-after-drop-duplicates/38235935#comment63893376_38235935) for comment):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
return df.to_dict(orient="records")
```

Or:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
return df.to_dict(orient="records")
```

Comment: That's right. To explain why this is, without the `()` the `drop_duplicates` just refers to the function, so `df` becomes a copy of the function, not the result of executing it.

Comment: @andychase, nice explanation, I add it to answer.